# Cómo implementar Trigger en JQuery en HTML OnClick?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola Buenas necesito ayuda con esto. mi objetivo aca es Que mi boton Siguiente Active como tal o ejecute el click de mi id=boton2 que va a mostrar lo que esta en panel2 al usuario. Tengo practicamente 1 problema Es que mi onClick no esta llamando la función ni tampoco esta funcionando mi jquery cuando hago a refencia escuchando eventos. Algun tip?

```
<ul hidden id="paneles" class="nav md-pills pills-secondary"> 
  <li><a href="#panel1" data-toggle="tab">Home 1</a></li>
  <li><a id="boton2" href="#panel2" data-toggle="tab">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>



<div id="panel1" class="container m-5 tab-pane fade in show active">
       <div class="form" style="top: 15vh;">
           <form id="form" class="form-group">
            <h1>1. Apertura de Camión</h1>
            <hr>
            <label><b>Subir Imagen</b></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="file">
            <hr>
            <button id="boton-crear" class="btn btn-primary">Volver</button>
            <button  onclick="next('#boton2')" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right;color:white" >Siguiente</button> 
         </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="panel2" class="container m-5 tab-pane fade">
       <div class="form" style="top: 15vh;">
           <form id="form" class="form-group">
            <h1>2. Inicio de Descarga</h1>
            <hr>
            <label><b>Subir Imagen</b></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="file">
            <hr>
            <button id="boton-crear" class="btn btn-primary">Volver</button>
            <a style="float:right;color:white" class="btn btn-primary">Siguiente</a> 
         </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
   function next(str){
 alert('Entraste AQUI POR FIN')
       $(str).trigger('click');
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Tu codigo funciona, agregaste la referencia a jquery?

Answer (score 1):

```
<button 
id="next" 
class="btn btn-primary" 
style="float:right;color:white"
>Siguiente</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    next.addEventListener('click', function(){
     $('#boton2').trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

Es posible acceder a los elementos a través del identificador id="next", espero únicamente que el jquery sea llamado antes del archivo (La función de arriba), para que el identificador: $() esté disponible.

```
<script src="jquery..."></script>
```

Comment: mi head tiene ese script que me trae jquery o tal vez estoy equivocado.                                      
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"</script>

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> Directamente de https://code.jquery.com.